# Blank page when Facebook app launch via Intent from my app

Tags: android, facebook

Once the Facebook app is launch, it only displays blank page. The page needs to be refresh for the profile to show. Here's my code.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://facebook.com/Username")));
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with their latest update last on Friday 7/15/16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the following uri

```
try{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("fb://profile/fb_id_of_the_profile"));
    startActivity(intent);
   }catch(Exception e){
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/username)));
  }
```

Replace "fb_id_of_the_profile" with the profile id

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("fb://profile/UserName"));     but it only launch the facebook app. I didnt display the given username's profile.

Comment: This url works fine in app browser "https://www.facebook.com/username" but if you wanted see the profile in Facebook android app you should follow the Facebook sdk integration in your project. Follow the steps [here](developers.facebook.com)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I replaced the code

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://facebook.com/Username")));`

with

`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/Username")));`

Comment: both the snippets are literally the same